# Static resources + web-inf + Spring Boot

Tags: java, css, spring, maven

I have a Spring Boot project. The project structure is like this :

```
src 
|-  main
     |-java
        |-demo
     |-resources 
        |-static
            |-css/mycss.css
```

When I run a maven build on this, my css gets packaged like this:

```
web-inf
    |-classes
        |-demo
        |-static
            |-css/mycss.css
```

My problem is why its is packages static resources inside "web-inf/classes" folder, I am not able to access my CSS via `localhost:8080/css/mycss.css or localhost:8080/static/css/mycss.css`

My pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: `/static/css/mycss.css` should work unless you are messing around with the default configuration of Spring Boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The src/main/resources is a default resource folder in maven, so by default configuration anything you put here will be in classpath so it will be put into WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: adding file to src/main/webapp/static/some-xml-file added files to
root-of-webapp/static/some-xml-file.

adding file to src/main/webapp/web-INF/some-xml-file did the trick and created correct folder structure and created structure 
root-of-webapp/WEB-INF/some-xml-file.
root-of-webapp/WEB-INF/other-structure-created-bydeault-by-spring -boot

Comment: I checked Spring boot's default config and according to it the resources/static/css/mycss.css file should be available at localhost:8080/css/mycss.css url.

So I edited my answer.

Comment: if i add  resources/static/css/mycss.css, structure to my project, what do u think would be the folder structure generated in target.

in my environment, its getting  packaged inside web-inf/classes/css/mycss.css,  and i dont think anything inside classes folder of web-inf would be accessible like static resource

Comment: Basically anything in WEB-INF folder is not accessible directly, but Spring resource servlet should return these resources.

Answer (score 0):

I am following the standard

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application){
        return application.sources(ConfigInitializer.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/*"); // required JBOSS EAP 6.2.0 GA
        super.onStartup(container);
    }
    private WebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(ConfigInitializer.class.getName());
        return context;
    }
}
```

what possibly i could be doing wrong?